# MQ - Get Multi Instance MQ Manager Connection List

Tags: java, ibm-mq

In a Java client app we are connecting to a multi-instance MQ Manager as follows:

```
java.net.URL ccdt = new URL("file:./config/qmgrs/MQMGR/AMQCLCHL.TAB");
MQQueueManager mqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager("*MQMGR", ccdt);
```

We can then for example enquire about the current depth of a queue as follows:

```
int openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE;
MQQueue mqQueue = mqQueueManager.accessQueue("A.QUEUE.NAME", openOptions);
System.out.println("queue depth:" + mqQueue.getCurrentDepth());
```

Question is, using the same MQQueueManager object, how can we get the list of multi-instance MQ Managers' addresses and ports. Or any other info about the manager itself...

We can see there is the following sort of thing available:

```
String nameList = mqQueueManager.getAttributeString(MQConstants.MQCA_NAMELIST_NAME, MQConstants.MQ_NAMELIST_NAME_LENGTH);
```

But when we call the above command, we get:

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2067'.
```

We are not sure if this is because the client code is not configured correctly or, if it is because the connection that we are using does not have sufficient permissions to get information about the manager?

Comment: Which namelist is it that you wish to inquire details of? I don't know of a namelist that lists the multi-instance MQ Queue Manager's addresses and ports. You are getting reason code 2067 (MQRC_SELECTOR_ERROR) because MQCA_NAMELIST_NAME is not a queue manager attribute, it is a namelist attribute. You would need to open the namelist for MQOO_INQUIRE. However, the real question is "Which Namelist?"

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use MQ PCF classes to query queue manager attributes. There is sample PCF_WalkThroughQueueManagerAttributes.java shipped with MQ that displays all attributes of queue manager. Here is small sample that lists local queues of a queue manager.

```
private void runPCFTest() {
    try {
    PCFAgent agent = new PCFAgent(connect());

    PCFParameter[] parameters = { new MQCFST (MQConstants.MQCA_Q_NAME, "*"), 
            new MQCFIN (MQConstants.MQIA_Q_TYPE, MQConstants.MQQT_LOCAL)};

    MQMessage[] responses = agent.send(CMQCFC.MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q_NAMES, parameters);
                MQCFH cfh = new MQCFH(responses[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < cfh.getParameterCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println (PCFParameter.nextParameter (responses [0]));
    }
}catch(Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
private MQQueueManager connect() throws MQException {
    Hashtable props = new Hashtable();
    props.put(MQConstants.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "localhost");
    props.put(MQConstants.PORT_PROPERTY, 1414);
    props.put(MQConstants.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "MFT_CHN");
    props.put(MQConstants.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "user1");
    props.put(MQConstants.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "passw0rd");
    props.put(MQConstants.USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION_PROPERTY, true);

    return new MQQueueManager("MQM", props);
}
```

But why do you want to query connection information, host, port etc?

Comment: We do know the ip addresses and ports on which our multi-instance managers are running but it would be nice to be able to query these values from within our java client application where we are connecting to these managers using CCDT tables only. And ultimately, we would also like our java client application to know which of the multi-instance managers is currently the active one. I have never worked with PCFAgent before but in your given example the connection is to a specific instance as opposed to whichever one is currently active for any given manager?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to know all of the hostnames (or IP addresses) and Port numbers of the servers where the MI queue manager may reside.  Correct?

This information is in your CCDT file.  When you (or MQAdmin) created your CCDT entry for the CLNTCONN (client-side channel), you would have issued a like:

```
DEFINE CHANNEL(TEST.CHL) CHLTYPE(CLNTCONN) TRPTYPE(TCP) CONNAME('ipaddr1(1414), ipaddr2(1414)') QMNAME(QM1)
```

Hence, the CONNAME parameter has the information and that is what the MQ client library uses to connect to the remote queue manager.  First it will try 'ipaddr1(1414)' and if it fails then it will try 'ipaddr2(1414)'.

Comment: the client app does have access to the CCDT file and that is how it is actually connecting to either MI Manager but this file is a binary file and therefore can't be easily parsed. We are only wondering if it is actually possible to get the IPs and ports using the MQQueueManager object itself and if its possible to query which MI is currently the active one without needing to probe each MI manager specifically.

Comment: Simple answer is no.  You can parse the CCDT file but I wouldn't advise it.  The best solution is to upgrade your MQ client to 9.1.2 or higher then the CCDT file can be in JSON format (rather than binary).  See: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q132890_.htm

Comment: Oh, we are on version 9 for our MQ Managers and using version 9 java client libraries. Not sure which version 9.x.x exactly we currently have installed (both server and clients) but this does sound promising. Will look at this as way to move forward with requirement.